# protecting jsp action pages with tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat

Sorry, this is basic but I'm not finding an answer easily.

Currently most of my pages fit the pattern

```
page.html -> action.jsp -> result.jsp
```

The page.html has a form and submits data to action.jsp which then redirects to result.jsp.
The user will never usually see the action page, but if they know the name they can just navigate to

```
action.jsp?parameter=thisisbad
```

for example.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a servlet instead of `action.jsp` and hide the `result.jsp` in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. In the `doGet()` method of the servlet just forward to `/WEB-INF/result.jsp`. In the `doPost()` method of the servlet, process the form submit and finally forward to `/WEB-INF/result.jsp`.

This way the enduser will never be able to open `result.jsp` directly. In the servlet you've full control over what you do on GET and POST requests.

#### See also:

- [Our servlets tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)